# Artifactory-Deployment with phing

Tags: artifactory, phing

Is it possible to deploy stuff into `Artifactory` with `phing`? I couldn't find anything useful by searching since `phing` is not very popular...

Answer (score 2):

From what I saw, `phing` supports `taskdef` for adding additional tasks. If that's true, go ahead and use [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). [It works perfect with Artifactory.](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Ivy)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having troubles setting up `ivy` & `phing`. Is there an example somewhere to be found? I could not get any information using google.

Comment: Maybe it worth a new question with your code sample and exact error information.

Comment: I'll try some other stuff with phing&maven first. If that doesn't work out, I'll open a new question regarding phing&ivy :)